# Retrieve file name from database in file upload control

Tags: .net, asp.net, file-upload

I have form for update product in which I have file upload control,
in update product form i have retrieved all other details of product in appropriate text boxes like `product name,price`,etc.

I also want to retrieve name and path of product image in file upload control which is uploaded using add product form.

Is it possible to set path of uploaded file to file upload control.

Plz help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can't retain/assign value in FileUpload control. This is because of due to browser security reasons.